# How to log detailed request info in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm having some trouble with a Bitbucket -> Jenkins plugin, and would like to see the exact API request that Jenkins is receiving.

I figure this should be fairly easy, but haven't been able to find the correct loggers to enable. I wanted to create a new Log Recorder, but do not know which loggers to enable to log the full incoming requests.

How can I enable request logging in Jenkins so I can see the full/exact request that is being made?